# Using NOT_CONTAINS in conditional write via DynamoDBMapper

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to update record in DynamoDB table based on below condition which states that "Update record only when attribute value belongs to none of the values specified in list".

Code Snippet:

```
AttributeValue inProgressStatus = new AttributeValue("IN_PROGRESS");
AttributeValue successStatus = new AttributeValue("SUCCESS");

ExpectedAttributeValue expectedAttributeValue = new ExpectedAttributeValue();
expectedAttributeValue.setAttributeValueList(Arrays.asList(inProgressStatus, successStatus));
expectedAttributeValue.setComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.NOT_CONTAINS);
```

While executing conditional update I am receiving following exception:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: One or more parameter values were invalid: 
Invalid number of argument(s) for the NOT_CONTAINS ComparisonOperator (Service: null; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: null).
```

Please let me know how can I achieve my functionality using `NOT_CONTAINS` operator.

Answer (score -1):

`NOT_CONTAINS` can only have a single `AttributeValue` and you have two. Refer to the documentation for DynamoDB conditions including `NOT_CONTAINS` at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html.

Comment: Not answering the actual question